# nextjs page redirects to homepage after refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-s3, next.js

created website using nextjs and using app based router, and deployed on aws s3 and the
issue is every time when i navigate to any page `www.example.com/about-us` and refresh the window it `redirects` me to `homepage`, `( / )`
but on local environment its not redirecting me to home (/) , its only happening on deployed site,

also tried npm run build and npm run start

here in config i added

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    
    output: "export"
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```